# query dependency chain of producers and requirements

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm setting up a graph structure with *transformers* that 'require' and 'produce' 1 or more Kafka topics. I can define the graph structure ok, but I'd like some help with a query.

I'd like to query: *what chain of transformers and topics are required to create a certain topic*, for instance in the sample below, what transformers are required to produce Topic3. I'd expect

```
Ingest1->Topic7->T1->Topic1->T2->Topic3
```

The first answer below isn't quite correct, because it doesn't take into account the alternating directions of requires and produces.
A correct query up to a certain depth would be something like

```
MATCH (topic:Topic{name:"topic-3"})
<-[:produces]- (tr1)  -[:requires]->(tp1) 
<-[:produces]- (tr2)  -[:requires]->(tp2) 
<-[:produces]- (tr3)  
return [topic,tr1,tp1,tr2,tp2,tr3] as List
```

So it seems I'm looking for something that can repeat the paired produces/requires vertices.

Here's some data that I'm playing with.

```
CREATE (DB1:Database {backbone: true, name:"postgres db 1"})
CREATE (Ingest1:Ingest {backbone: true, name: "ingest-1"})

CREATE (KV1:KV {name: "key-value store 1"})
CREATE (KV2:KV {name: "key-value store 2"})
CREATE (KV1)-[:requires]->(DB1)
CREATE (KV2)-[:requires]->(DB1)
CREATE (Topic1:Topic {name: "topic-1", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic2:Topic {name: "topic-2", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic3:Topic {name: "topic-3", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic4:Topic {name: "topic-4", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic5:Topic {name: "topic-5", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic6:Topic {name: "topic-6", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic7:Topic {name: "topic-7", partitions:100})
CREATE (Topic8:Topic {name: "topic-8", partitions:100})
CREATE (T2:Transformer {name: "T2"})
CREATE (T1:Transformer {name: "T1"})
CREATE (T3:Transformer {name: "T3"})
CREATE (T4:Transformer {name: "T4"})
CREATE (T5:Transformer {name: "T5"})
CREATE (T6:Transformer {name: "T6"})
CREATE (T7:Transformer {name: "T7"})
CREATE (T8:Transformer {name: "T8"})
CREATE (T9:Transformer {name: "T9"})
CREATE (T4)-[:requires]->(Topic3)
CREATE (T5)-[:requires]->(Topic3)
CREATE (T2)-[:produces]->(Topic3)
CREATE (T2)-[:produces]->(Topic4)
CREATE (T2)-[:produces]->(KV1)
CREATE (T2)-[:requires]->(Topic1)
CREATE (T4)-[:produces]->(Topic5)

CREATE (T2)-[:requires]->(Topic2)
CREATE (T1)-[:produces]->(Topic1)
CREATE (T1)-[:requires]->(Topic7)
CREATE (T3)-[:produces]->(Topic2)
CREATE (T3)-[:requires]->(Topic8)
CREATE (Ingest1)-[:produces]->(Topic7)
CREATE (Ingest1)-[:produces]->(Topic8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
// find the transformer from the selected topic
MATCH (topic3:Topic {name: "topic-3"})<-[produces]-(transformer:Transformer)

// find the path(s) back from the transformer to the ingest
MATCH p=(transformer)-[:produces|requires*]-(i:Ingest)

// put the names in a collection from topic3 back to ingest
WITH reduce(chain = [topic3.name], n in nodes(p) | chain + n.name) as chain

// return the collection in the desired order
RETURN reverse(chain)
```

It could be simplified to this as well

```
MATCH p=(topic3:Topic {name: "topic-3"})-[:produces|requires*]-(i:Ingest)
WITH reduce(chain = [topic3.name], n in nodes(p) | chain + n.name) as chain
RETURN reverse(chain)
```

Comment: I don't think your first solution is quite correct :-)
I've added a few transformers and topics in the definition (see editted question), and the second query returns:

    `[ingest-1, topic-7, T1, topic-1, T2, topic-3, topic-3]`
    `[ingest-1, topic-8, T3, topic-2, T2, topic-3, topic-3]`
    `[ingest-1, topic-7, T1, topic-1, T2, topic-3, topic-3]`
    `[ingest-1, topic-8, T3, topic-2, T2, topic-3, topic-3]`

The logic is correct